# Uniqueness of solution to a nonlinear second order ODE.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y=y(t), \, t\ge 0$ be a solution to the ODE $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{1}{t}\frac{dy}{dt}-(\frac{dy}{dt})^2=0$ with the initial condition $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$.  So far I found a particular solution $y=\ln(\frac{2}{1+t^2})$. My question is that does such solution have to be unique?

I first tried the substitution $z=y'$, and got $z'-\frac{z}{t}-z^2=0$ with $z(0)=0$. I'm stucking here because I cannot show the uniqueness of the solution $z$.

Any comments or ideas will be really appreciated.

Comment: How is the ODE defined at $t=0$?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm understanding the term $\frac{1}{t}\frac{dy}{dt}$ at $t=0$ in the sense that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} y'(t)/t=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, I also updated the post, and gave a particular solution to such ODE.

Comment: $y=0$ is also a solution, so uniqueness at $t=0$ is lost...